# Merge two hive table(Different column size)- pyspark

Tags: pyspark, hive, hiveql, apache-spark-sql

I have one hive table with schema 
**Name ,Contact,Address,Subject**

```
Name  Contact   Address  Subject
abc   1111      Mumbai    maths
egf   2222      nashik    science
pqr   3333      delhi     history

And other table with schema **Name ,Contact** 
Name   Contact
xyz    4444  
mno    2222
```

Expected Output

```
Name  Contact   Address  Subject
abc   1111      Mumbai    maths
pqr   3333      delhi     history
xyz   4444      null      null
mno   2222      nashik    science
```

I have tried join operation but not able get correct output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use full join:

```
select coalesce(t2.name,t1.name) as name, 
       coalesce(t2.contact, t1.contact) as contact,
       t1.address, t1.subject
  from table1 t1
       full join table2 t2
                 on t1.contact=t2.contact
```